# Expectation with continuous random variables: robot and tokens.

Tags: probability

(No, this is not homework. I am working through the exercises in Ross' *Probability Models for Computer Science* myself, so I don't have a tutor that I can ask for help/hints. This is one of the first exercise that involves calculating the expectation of continuous random variables.)

**Each of $n$ tokens is, independent of the others, uniformly located on the rim of a circle of circumference 1. Starting at a fixed point $P$, a robot must travel around the rim of the circle so as to pick up all the tokens. The robot must travel either in a clockwise or a counterclockwise direction; it observes the locations of the tokens and makes its choice so as to minimise its total overall traveling distance $X$.**

1. Find $E[D]$, where $D$ is the distance from $P$ to the nearest token.
2. Suppose that the nearest token is in the clockwise direction from $P$, and find $E[B]$, where $B$ is the distance from $P$ to the nearest token when going in the other direction.
3. Find $E[X]$.

My attempts:

1. I *think* I've calculated it correctly as $\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$, and convinced myself with a computer simulation.

Let $D_i$, $1 \leq i \leq n$, denote the distance from $P$ to the $i$th token, which is the minimum over travelling either clockwise or counterclockwise from $P$ to the token. Using $E[D] = \int_0^\infty P(D>t)\,dt$,

$$
\begin{split}
        E[D]    & = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} P(D>t) \,dt \\
                & = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} \prod_{i=1}^n P( D_i>t )\, dt \text{, by independence of $D_i$} \\
                & = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} \prod_{i=1}^n (1-P(D_i \leq t))\, dt \\
                & = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} (1-2t)^n\, dt \\
                & = -\frac{1}{2(n+1)}(1-2t)^{n+1}\big|_0^\frac{1}{2} \\
                & = \frac{1}{2(n+1)}\text.
\end{split}
$$

2. I'm stuck here. I assume when the question defines $B$ as the "distance from $P$ to the nearest token when going in the other direction", it means the token closest to $P$ going in the counter-clockwise direction.

Let $T_i$ for $i\in[1,n]$ denote the distance to the $i$th token going clockwise from $P$. Let $B'=1-B$ denote the distance from $P$ to the *last* token, $T_n$, when traveling clockwise. Assume the nearest token is in the clockwise direction. Then, $0<=T_1<\frac{1}{2}$ and, for $j>1$, $T_1<T_j<1-T_1$.

Let $f(t)$ denote the probability density function of $T_1$.

$$
\begin{split}
1-E[B] = E[B'] & = E[E[B'|T_1]] \\
     & = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} f(t)\cdot E[B'|T_1=t]\, dt \\
     & = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} f(t)\cdot \int_t^{1-t}P(B'>u|T_1=t)\, du \ dt \\
     & = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} f(t)\cdot \int_t^{1-t}P(T_2>u,...,T_n>u|T_1=t)\, du \ dt \\
     & = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} f(t)\cdot \int_t^{1-t}P(T_2>u,...,T_n>u|t<T_2<1-t, ..., t<T_n<1-t)\, du \ dt \\
     & = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} f(t)\cdot \int_t^{1-t}P(T_2>u,...,T_n>u|t<T_2<1-t, ..., t<T_n<1-t)\, du \ dt \\
     & = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} f(t)\cdot \int_t^{1-t}(\frac{1-t-u}{1-2t})^n\, du \ dt \\
     & = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} f(t)\cdot \frac{1-2t}{n+1} \,dt \\
\end{split}
$$

I've tried various different definitions of $f$, and failed to produce results that are consistent with the computer simulation. For what it's worth, the simulation produces, as $E[B]$,

trials=200000

```
n=1  0.7504939920638828
n=2  0.4997894010396945
n=3  0.3752038358859654
n=4  0.30064565733168563
n=5  0.2500781413888529
n=6  0.21446670918531544
n=7  0.18749227038267502
n=8  0.1673145383430258
n=9  0.15002755476368163
n=10  0.13645895982382442
```

I've stressed long enough on this problem that I'd happily take a solution. Otherwise, corrections and a definition of $f$ would be a great help.

3. I think this involves determining the algorithm that minimises the total overall traveling distance. It seems clear to me that the distance $X$ is determined by the distance of the furthest token, whichever direction is chosen, and the expected distance given the robot travels clockwise is equal to the expected distance given the robot travels counterclockwise by the uniform placement of tokens. I have a nagging feeling that the structure of the question wants me to incorporate $E[X]$ and $E[B]$ into the solution, but it isn't apparent to me how.

Comment: Can you include your working and not just state the solution that you found?

Comment: For the second problem, the solution is most likely 1/(2(n+1)) + 1/(n+1), which is the expected distance to the closest + the expected distance between the dots (which matches your numerical findings; thanks for putting them there). Finding E[X] seems miserable, and I have no clue how.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work it out. The mistake in the calculation of 2 is that the expectation should be from $u=0$:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\frac{1}{2} f(t)\cdot \int_0^{1-t}P(B'>u|T_1=t)\, du \ dt
\end{equation}

That gives the same result as @E-A mentions in the comments, $\frac{3}{2n+2}$. I haven't been able to intuitively grasp the reasoning behind his solution, though (would welcome a comment explanation).

The answer to 3 is simplified by the condition "the robot must travel either in a clockwise or a counterclockwise direction". Suppose the nearest token is clockwise. Then the expected value of $X$ is just $1-E[B]$. (The same result is found with a symmetric argument if you supposed the nearest token were anti-clockwise).